# how to write a regular expression to check a character only could appear once?

Tags: regex

I really need help. Currently, I have this expression to check the username but I want to add more to check if more than one period or underscore is in the string. If it is, return false. if it is not, return true.

```
^([_.a-z0-9]{3,15})$
```

For example, the following cases will return *`True`*:

```
.yhjgh899_
_.9874juyh
899j_nnfg
874083.
```

The following cases will return *`False`*:

```
_jdun_jd.
jkuf..jf
```

Comment: The regular expressions are a powerful tool but they are not a one-size-fits-all tool. Some processing can be done easily (or even easier) **without** regular expressions. Try a simple approach: test the input string against the regular expression `_` and see how many times it matches. Or, without regular expressions, replace the string `_` with an empty string and compare the length of the modified string against the length of the original. If the difference is more than 1 then the input string contains duplicate `_` characters. The advantage of this approach is the code readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative lookahead at the start:

```php
^(?!.*?([._]).*?\1)[_.a-z0-9]{3,15}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEy1M3/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*?([._]).*?\1)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then a `.` or `_` (captured into Group 1, that can be referred to as `\1`), then again zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then the same value as stored in Group 1
- `[_.a-z0-9]{3,15}` - three to fifteen lowercase ASCII letters, digits or `.` / `_`
- `$` - end of string.